# Java Web Servlet is not working after deployed to a folder

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

As i mentioned in the title i deployed my java web project to tomcat path `/Test2` (before it was deployed to tomcat ROOT and all was working perfectly) and all my webServlets stop working.Here's my servlet settings;

```
@WebServlet(
    name = "SessionLab",
    urlPatterns = {"/search","/newcontact","/gosearch","/gocontact","/index"},
    initParams = {
            @WebInitParam(name = "filename", value = "addressBook.txt")
    })
```

and there was this function to find the relevant urlpath and forward the request

```
 if(request.getRequestURI().equals("/search")) {
        readAddressbook(request, response);
    }
    else if(request.getRequestURI().equals("/newcontact")) {
        addnewContact(request, response);
    }
     .........<so on>
```

Everything stopped working after i deploy them to folder path rather than ROOT of tomcat9. I even changed the `web.xml` for url mapping as follows;

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SessionLab</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.AddressBookServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SessionLab</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Test2/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Still its not working, i getting 404 error. how to fix this?

Comment: `<url-pattern>/Test2/*</url-pattern>` you should not do so. In `web.xml` you must specify URLs relative to the context path (which is `/Test2` in your case).

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy okay i changed url pattern to `<url-pattern>/Test2/</url-pattern>` and changed `@webservlet urls to "Test2/gosearch".. ` still not working

Comment: You don' tneed to change @WebServlet urls either. They need to stay `/gosearch` and so on. You application does not need to know anything about that `/Test2` prefix, everything is done by a container (Tomcat) when you deploy under context `/Test2` there.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the url pattern to /*, and hit the page.

Comment: Did you remove the Root war?

Comment: there is no root app to run in localhost:8080 , only in `localhost:8080/Test2`